# Changes in symlinked hosts file need restart to be effective in Windows 10

Tags: windows, windows-10, hosts, hosts-file

On my Windows computer, I have started using symlink for the `hosts` file and placed the original file somewhere else.

Everything is working fine, except if I change something to the original file, it doesn't get reflected on real-time. I need to restart computer to take that into effect. The timestamp (file date) of the symbolic link does not change when editing the real file.

Is there any way to refresh the cache of hosts file in Windows 10?

Comment: So I guess that the timestamp (file date) of the symbolic link does not change when editing the real file?

Comment: Yes you are correct. I can see that modified time is never changing. So how can I let it do so?

Comment: If you're sure that it's caused by the timestamp not changing, then I guess the question's title should be: *How to make symbolic link's timestamp change when original file is edited?*